# Different dendrograms with two programs

Tags: r, dendrogram

I am currently working on the classification of bacteria. For this, I am building dendrograms ([diagrams representing a tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram)) with two softwares (Rstudio and BioNumerics) in order to verify the results. I use the same coefficient and algorithms for the construction of the dendrograms in both software.
But I don't get the same classifications.

Is it normal not to get the same results?

I tried to change the construction parameters of the dendrograms. But I did not get the same results.

Comment: As someone who isn't familiar with this use-case: any chance there is random sampling involved in the classifications?
I think it's a long-shot that someone will be able to answer this question without any replicable data in both software. Take a quick read here first: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)